# Is there a way to hide the tooltip with html <a> title attribute?

Tags: html, hide, title

I want the the tooltip not be displayed when the mouse hovers over the links although the title attribute should be there for it affects SEO.
I've read about removing using jQuery with $('...').removeAttr('title'); but does this still generate the title atribute in html for the search engine crawlers to crawl??

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322839/is-it-possible-to-hide-href-title

Comment: Write for humans, not search engines. Odds are that if you don't want people to see it, it is going to do you more harm than good in the long run as far as search engines are concerned. (Although I'd be amazed if search engines paid any attention to title attributes in the first place).

Comment: well, i dint want to display the tooltip concerning about the user experience. When the tooltips show up, it hides the drop down menu from view and raise a question of usability. It's not even an image, just links where the anchor is the same as the title so i thought it would be best if it stays hidden.
Thanks.

Comment: If it duplicates information already in the element, it would be best if it didn't exist.

Comment: well, maybe i should just remove it then. :)

Comment: Stop SEOing. Let search engine providers worry about optimizing search engines.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry too much about titles for search index optimization. Most search engines place a heavier weight based on external links that link to your site than they do title attributes.

If you really care, you could always hide the title attribute on a mouse event, which certainly wouldn't affect crawlers.