# Is it possible to hide title when hovering image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, html, css

This is my code:

```
<img src="image.jpg" alt="" title="some title" />
```

When I hover that image "some title" appears. Is it possible to be hidden?

Comment: Wouldn't you prefer removing it? If you don't wanna show it on hover, when do you use the title?

Comment: Have you tried something? Do you want to permanently remove the title?

Comment: I use jQuery to get title from image and display it on image. I don't need it on hover then.

Comment: why do you want to do that? title is made for that purpose, if you want to add a custom attribute to the tag write something like data-title="some title" or use the alt attribute

Comment: i think you can easily find this here .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322839/is-it-possible-to-hide-href-title

Comment: @Onheiron I think I'll go with your solution (data-title instead of title) although there are 5 good answers here :) Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be easily done as some answers point out, but knowing what you want to do with title, I would use a data-* custom attribute or attach the title with .data()

```
<img src="image.jpg" alt="" data-title="some title" />
```

or

```
$('img').data('title', 'some title');
```

Comment: Yes, I'll go with this solution as it fits my needs the most, although each answer to this question is equally good :) I just think it would make more sense to move it to data-title instead of hiding original title="" on hover. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If it's just a question of hover, you can make `pointer-events: none;` on image, and it will fix the issue.

Answer (score 4):

It's simple enough to remove the `title` attribute, but 'hiding it' is not possible (so far as I'm aware); in order to remove the title the following should work, though currently untested:

```
$('img').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).data('originalTitle',$(this).title());
        $(this).removeAttr('title');
    },
    function(){
        $(this).attr('title',$(this).data('originalTitle');
    });
```

In the above I've chosen to move the attribute, and then replace it on mouse-out.

To remove the `title` permanently:

```
$('img').removeAttr('title');
```

References:

- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
- [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).
- [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).
- [`removeAttr()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/).

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It obviously works and I could use it but I think I'll go with data-title="" instead as one of the other answers suggests. It just makes more sense in my case because I'm printing title tag on top of image using jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

You can move it to image data... and back. Like that

```
$('img').hover(
  function () {
    $(this).data('title',$(this).attr('title')).removeAttr('title');
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).attr('title',$(this).data('title'));
  }
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution! It obviously works but I decided to go with data-title attribute instead. Other answers convinced me that it's better method in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! with jQuery you can remove it on mouseover and add it again onmouseout -

```
$(function(){
  var ttext;
  $('img').hover(function(){
    ttext = $(this).attr('title');
    $(this).removeAttr('title');
  },
  function(){
    $(this).attr('title', ttext);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution! It obviously works but I decided to go with data-title attribute instead. Other answers convinced me that it's better method in my case.

Answer (score 0):

No, not really. But you could replace it with JavaScript, or just leave it blank.

jQuery example:

```
$('[title]').removeAttr('title');
```

Answer (score 0):

Kind of hilarious that on Stack Overflow, five people can give the same answer at the same time :P

```
$(function(){
    $('img').hover(function(){
        $(this).removeAttr('title');
    }, function(){
        $(this).attr('title','some title');
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, I just posted the question and 5 answers appeared at the same time two minutes later :) Each one is alike.

Answer (score 0):

Something I tried and worked with jQuery / jQuery UI on Chrome at least:

1. Create the object you want (and don't want) to have a title.
2. Once all these items exist, add a tooltip.
3. Go through all items you don't want the tooltip displaying the usual way, and set the tooltip to `''`.

Example from my code, occuring after named HTML elements are available:

```
jQuery(document).tooltip();
for(var index = 0; index < sites.length; ++index) {
    jQuery('#' + sites[index][0]).attr('title', '');
}
```