# Turn Off Alt Tags On Links With CSS?

Tags: css

[This website](http://www.2touchrulz.com) that I'm working on has annoying alt tags popping up when you hover over links in the sidebar. I didn't put these alt tags in. But, I can control the CSS... Is there anyway to disable them?

Thank you!

Tara

Comment: can you control the css via a firefox plugin?

Comment: No, I can edit the CSS in the style.css

Comment: It looks like your site is in some sort of content management system.  Do you have administrative access to that?

Comment: Also, since you have access to CSS... you might consider NOT changing the font size when you hover over links.  It's really distracting how it shifts the rest of the menu, especially when the larger size causes a menu item to suddenly wrap to the next line.

Comment: @eaj It's a wordpress template, so technically I have access to all of it but I don't know anything about php or js so I'm limited by my lack of ability.

Comment: Tried CSS - pointer-events: none; ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simple answer: **no**

They are impossible to turn off just with CSS. They are **browser dependant** and are not part of any CSS spec i.e. you can't style them, hide them, anything.

Though you can get rid of them by Javascript:

### Javascript

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++)
{
  elements[i].removeAttribute('title');
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Gary - I don't know much about JS, but I tried pasting '<script> 
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++)
{
  elements[i].removeAttribute('title');
}
</script>'

into the index.php file and it made no difference... Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: maybe the document is not fully loaded yet?  Try putting the script at the bottom of the page (before </body>) or if that doesn't work, call it from the onload event

Answer (score 2):

They're actually `title` tags  and you can't remove them with css (you can with javascript) but I guess they're there for a reason.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS like below:

```
    pointer-events: none;
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see of the site, you’re getting a tooltip when you hover over the side bar links because they each have a `title` attribute.

I don’t think there’s anything in CSS to prevent these showing up. Showing these in a tooltip on hover is a decision the browser makes, separately to the rendering of the HTML.

The best you can do is [use JavaScript to remove the `title` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299772/jquery-hide-native-tooltip-resolved).

Comment: Thanks... could I just paste that script straight into a php file or do I need to embed it or something? Sorry! JS noob...

Comment: @Tara: ah, right — the script relies on jQuery, so you’d need that on the page too. You also need the script to run after your HTML has finished loading, so you could chuck both at the bottom of your page: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script><script>TITLE REMOVING CODE GOES HERE</script></body></html>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **CSS** to hide images with any alt text, for example alt = "LinkedIn"

`[alt="LinkedIn"] {
    display: none !important;
}`

You can also hide the image with title for example title = "Company logo"

`[title="Company logo"] {
    display: none !important;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Dear stackoverflow members, 
I wanted to remove the img alt attribute, to remove the alt thing, with css, without changing html php, or  adding java elements.
I wanted simply this box (border) around the image that is appearring to be removed. I could not find anywhere this simple solution! So i post it here! I hoep will help someone! I include a screenshot.

I made height and width to be exact with the picture, no more, no less.
Also, check that font-size attribute  element was set to 0.

That is (dependign on other set attributes, you may also need to adjust them, in order this "box" be adjusted to the exact size of your image:

```
#your_specific_ID_name .image_myclass_image {
   background-position: 0px 0px;
   height: 'the height of your image';
   width: 'the width of your image';
   font-size: 0;
}
```

[image]