# Remove ALT title tag when no access to html

Tags: javascript, css

I have integrated a web software in my website and I want remove the annoying ALT title tag displayed. The problem is I can't have access to html because the software is located on remote server. The only thing I'm able to do is to use external CSS or Javascript because those file are located on my own host and can interact with remote software.

The code is:

```
<td class="available" title="Click here please" onclick="window.top.location.href='http://www.site.com'"></td>
```

I make some search/test but it seem is not possible to use CSS for hide the title. I seen a javascript solution here:

[Turn Off Alt Tags On Links With CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871239/turn-off-alt-tags-on-links-with-css)

but this don't work for my case. Using Jquery is also not adapted for me.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: There are potential accessibility issues associated with doing something like this.

Comment: the `[title]` attribute is *not* the same as the `[alt]` attribute. Please stop using them interchangeably.

Comment: Is this "software" in an iframe?

Comment: I'm confused, which one of the two are you trying to remove?

Comment: Yes is an iframe integrated using a PHP snippet. I tried to remove or hide "Click here please".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution, using [document.createTreeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/document.createTreeWalker), for removing an attribute from a selected element and all of it's child elements.

HTML

```
<div id="removeHere" title="titled 0">
    <div title="titled 1">some text 1</div>
    <div title="titled 2">some text 2
        <div title="titled 3">some text 3
            <div title="titled 4">some text 4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div title="titled 5">some text 5</div>
</div>
<div title="titled 6">some text 6</div>
```

Javascript

```
(function (global) {
    function removeAttributeWalker(node, attribute) {
        var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(
        node,
        NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, {
            acceptNode: function () {
                return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
            }
        },
        false);

        node.removeAttribute(attribute);

        while (treeWalker.nextNode()) {
            treeWalker.currentNode.removeAttribute(attribute);
        }
    }

    global.addEventListener("load", function onLoad() {
        global.removeEventListener("load", onLoad);
        removeAttributeWalker(document.getElementById("removeHere"), "title");
    }, false);
}(window));
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/tdhdT/)

Update: If you need to support older browsers that do not have the above method, then the following could be used instead.

Javascript

```
(function (global) {
    function removeAttributeWalker(node, attribute) {
        if (node.nodeType === 1) {
            node.removeAttribute(attribute);
            node = node.firstChild;
            while (node) {
                removeAttributeWalker(node, attribute);
                node = node.nextSibling;
            }
        }
    }

    global.addEventListener("load", function onLoad() {
        global.removeEventListener("load", onLoad);
        removeAttributeWalker(document.getElementById("removeHere"), "title");
    }, false);
}(window));
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/7X4WB/)

Comment: thank for suggestion but this don't work too in my case. It seem really I'm a bit restricted in how to use JS for be able to interact with the remote software. However I seen document.createTreeWalker is not compatible with IE8. So even if this solution was functional, the incompatibility with IE8 was not acceptable.

Comment: You should really consider specifying which browsers you wish to support in your question, we are unable to guess.

Comment: I accept your updated answer because you make the proof is a working solution for support IE8. However this don't work for my case but is not your fault. As I said, the method who allow me to use JS is a bit unconventional due to the fact I try to interact with a code not hosted on my side. The problem could be also a conflict with some other JS.. Thank.

Answer (score 2):

Adapting the code you pointed to, to make it look at `td` elements rather than `a`, should work:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++)
{
    elements[i].removeAttribute('title');
}
```

Comment: yes I tried already this but without success. maybe is due to the fact the external JS do not work for this case.

Comment: your messages are comfusing, you said you can use javascript, but now you can't? Can you be more specific about where you put the code?

Comment: yes I can and I tried to use the code above but this don't work. I use some other JS code without problem. The code above maybe do not work for my case. For be more precise the JS is not external is only the CSS who is.. JS must be apply right after the snippet code I use for integrate the software. Maybe is the reason why this don't work..