# Url link shows upon drag, it should be hidden

Tags: javascript

I'm building a gallery in ReactJs and have draggable thumbs below main image.
The problem is, whenever I drag a thumb, its link url drags with the mouse.

http://prntscr.com/76kfrk

[image]

Is it possible to hide the url on drag?

Preferably using with Vanilla Js

Comment: Possible duplicate (just not with the same words) of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871239/turn-off-alt-tags-on-links-with-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's the `title` of the `a`-tag (you didn't set an `alt title`, so it displays the url), you should be able to hide it with the following bit of Javascript:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++)
{
  elements[i].removeAttribute('title');
}
```

Comment: Doing so, removes the title/link however creates ghost images: http://prntscr.com/76kljg

Comment: Try looking at this demo and applying it to your situation: http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/TB5Uf/2/

Answer (score 0):

This can be prevented with a [preventDefault](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#syntheticevent) on the [onMouseDown](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#mouse-events) event.

```
//React Component
someFunc: function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
},
render: function() {
  return (<img src="somepicture.jpg" onMouseDown={this.someFunc} />)
}
```

Comment: This would be a good idea, but since it's a slider it also prevents the slide functionality

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out below, the only way I know to prevent this is by calling event.preventDefault().

If you are using a special plugin for the slider then I would suggest you to take a look into its docs to see how you can receive the mousedown event when the user starts the drag.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be prevented by using the CSS property `-webkit-user-drag: none;` for  elements.