# Styling native tooltip from title="Tooltip text"

Tags: css, input, tooltip, title

I have input element that has title attribute which of course will result with tooltip with message of the attribute value.

For some reason this tooltip needs to be styled with css.

How can it be done? I do not know in which container it will be rendered, I do not know nothing about it. Also it cannot be accessed by developer tools of firebug