# Controlling browser tooltip(title) in html

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Styling native tooltip from title=“Tooltip text”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927640/styling-native-tooltip-from-title-tooltip-text)

Is any way to control browser tooltip in CSS.

like adjust height and width .. something

-spk-

Answer (score 1):

Not for the built in tooltips with `title`, no.

You can create tooltip-like constructs of your own, though, by using a div (or anything) that is hidden until the user hovers over your element. See the [:hover](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/%3ahover) pseudo-class.