# Tooltip for GWT

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

GWT does provide tooltip with something like:

```
Label label = new Label("test");
label.setTitle("This is a tooltip");
```

**Is there a way to style such tooltips? Is there a library for GWT that supports this?**

Edit: How do I set the time for the tooltip to appear?

Comment: The usual approach would be to use CSS.

Comment: I want to style the tooltip not the Label!

Comment: Have you inspected the DOM at all? Is the tooltip just an attribute or a widget drawn by GWT? What classes are applied?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no effort to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use GWTQuery for doing tooltip, there are a Plugin for that.
GwtQuery is a clone of JQuery but build in java.

You can find the demo here :

http://arcbees.github.io/ArcBees-GQuery-Plugins/

With this sample code, you can create toolkit for all title in the page :

```
$("[title]", toolbar).as(Tooltip).tooltip();
```

And the source code is here : 
https://github.com/ArcBees/ArcBees-GQuery-Plugins/tree/master/tooltip

Answer (score 1):

The real answer to your question is : **`No`**, native tooltip style can't be modified.

Alternatives are creating your own tooltips:

- [CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927640/styling-native-tooltip-from-title-tooltip-text)
- JS (Libraries)

Note that if you keep using the `title` attribute the native tooltip will be shown over your custom tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS
First, you add the style you want in your css
Then you set that style to the element you want with `label.setStyleName("myStyle");`

Comment: I want to style the tooltip not the Label!

Answer (score 0):

Tooltips can be styled with CSS. You can use one of the online tools:

http://csstooltip.com/

http://www.menucool.com/tooltip/css-tooltip

Comment: How do I set the time for the tooltip to appear?

Comment: You can't do it in CSS. You can set "title" on a Label when you want (e.g. on MouseOver, etc.)

Comment: I could use a PopupPresenter to show the tooltip. Do you know ho I can bind a MouseOver event on all elements that have a title attribute set? Do I have to delete the title attribute that the default browser tooltip does not show up the same time?

Comment: Don't set 'title" and there will be no default popup. You create handlers for MouseOver events the same way as for any other events in GWT.