# Styling native tooltip for any browser

Tags: jquery, css

Suppose I had the following HTML:

```
<a href="#" title="Multi Function"><img src="..."></a>
```

Is there a jQuery plugin to style the browser's default tooltip or can this be done with CSS?

Comment: -1 This question is of poor quality and lacking substance.  Please improve it.

Comment: you have google for these type of problems .
[Google](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=tooltip+plugin+in+jquery)

Comment: See http://qtip2.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery to do that.
For example, if you need to change the scrollbar: http://www.net-kit.com/jquery-custom-scrollbar-plugins/

Answer (score 0):

**Nope.**

There is currently no way to style the browser's default tooltip.

Your best bet is to use a JavaScript library built to replace the default tooltip entirely (eg: [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)'s, [jQuery Tool](http://jquerytools.org/documentation/tooltip/)'s, etc.). There is also a clever CSS trick you can do to replace the default tooltip ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927640/styling-native-tooltip-from-title-tooltip-text)). Note that each creates a *substitute* for the tooltip and *doesn't* style the tooltip itself.

Comment: JavaScript plugin Link? please

Comment: As @AmitKumar mentioned, "you have google for these type of problems." However, as per your request I added a link to jQuery UI's Tooltip tool.

Comment: Yes but all are Difficult to use, there is any easy plugin can change title="..." tooltip?

Comment: If jQuery UI's `$(document).tooltip()` is too difficult, we may have another problem.