# Image floating tags

Tags: html, css, image, floating

Here I have a weebly website, but I'm trying to make my own website and implement some of the features from the weebly website to my own.

I was wondering what this feature is called and how I would implement it:

[image: Animated Screenshot]

As you can see when you hover over an image a little floating tag appears, and I was just wondering if someone could tell me what it is and how I would implement it into my code:

Here is the code:

HTML

```
<div id="staff_images">
<center>
<img src="images/GR412.png" />
<img src="images/JoeVis.png" />
<img src="images/Scott.png" />
<img src="images/Halo.png" />
</center>
</div>
```

Comment: add `title=" "` to your images... with the name inside the `" "`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work is this correct? <img src="images/GR412.png" title="GR412" />

Comment: `<center>`?! Really???

Comment: @Grant Check my answer and click on the demo, you can see that when you hover, that you get the name of the images given in the title..

Comment: Yeah no tag appears over the image like the GIF I posted. It's still just a static image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `title=" "` to your images... with the name inside the `" "`. That should do it.

Like this:

```
<img src="images/GR412.png" title="GR412" />
<img src="images/JoeVis.png" title="JoeVis" />
<img src="images/Scott.png" title="Scott" />
<img src="images/Halo.png" title="Halo" />
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n12v3u9t/)**

Comment: Ahh I didn't add the CSS give us a min

Comment: I added this CSS code and no tag appears over the image. #staff_images img title {width:100px; height:100px;}

Comment: @Grant - the basic tooltip will show for you using C travels answer. If you want to apply your own style, refer to [this question over here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9927640/2930477). You would have to apply the style to a wrapping element around each image such as `<a>`

Comment: in what browser do you test it? and you can't use css with my answer to make it bigger or something...

Comment: Oh my goodness I'm so dumb, I forgot to hold it over for like 2 seconds. I'm so sorry. Your answer does work thanks!