# Adding tooltip to SVG rect tag

Tags: html, css, svg, tooltip, title

What's the best solution for adding tooltip to `<rect>`?

I've created SVG map with several `<rect>` tags and I'd like to show tooltip on mouseover. Using `title` attribute is fine but is there any option how to restyle it using CSS/Javascript/jQuery or is there even better option for adding tooltip?

```
<svg version="1.1" baseProfile="basic" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 50 50" xml:space="preserve">
    <g>
        <rect id="1" title="There's some text" x="0" y="0" fill="#666666" width="20" height="20"/>
        <rect id="2" title="There's another text" x="30" y="0" fill="#666666" width="20" height="20"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

SVG uses title elements, not attributes, you **can't** style them though. If you need styling you'd need to create the title dynamically as a `<text>` element and place it at the right location using javascript.

This is what default tooltips look like...

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 50 50" xml:space="preserve">
    <g>
        <rect id="1" fill="#666666" width="20" height="20">
          <title>There's some text</title>
        </rect>
        <rect id="2" x="30" fill="#666666" width="20" height="20">
          <title>There's another text</title>
        </rect>
   </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks. How am I supposed to style these `<title>` tags then?

Comment: That's not possible, you'll need to roll your own as I already stated in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

i tried your code but it doesn't work (Chrome). Then i found in this site a post about tooltip:

[How to add a tooltip to an svg graphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643426/how-to-add-a-tooltip-to-an-svg-graphic)

so instead of add the title attribute, you need to do like this:

```
<rect id="1" x="0" y="0" fill="#666666" width="20" height="20"><title>"There's some text"</title/></rect>
```

**UPDATE**

you can change the text and style with javascript and jquery

Example:

```
$("#1").find("title").html("Text")
```

Comment: Thanks. But is there any way how to style these?

Comment: also check out this post about css native tooltip:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927640/styling-native-tooltip-from-title-tooltip-text

Comment: You can change the html of title but styling doesn't work: `$("#1").find("title").css("color", "red")`

Comment: Anyway thanks for help. This is probably not the right solution. I think I'm gonna have to use some plugin for that.

Comment: you cannot style the default tooltip, but the previous link shows an alternative.