# get this anchor title text jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get all anchor title text inside children div's

My HTML

```
<div onClick="openList();">
  <div class="inc">
    <div class="iWrap">
        <a title="<div>blah1 blah1</div>"></a>
        <a title="<div>blah2 blah2</div>"></a>
        <a title="<div>blah3 blah3</div>"></a>
        <a title="<div>blah4 blah4</div>"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div onClick="openList();">
  <div class="inc">
    <div class="iWrap">
        <a title="<div>some text 1</div>"></a>
        <a title="<div>some text 2</div>"></a>
        <a title="<div>some text 3</div>"></a>
        <a title="<div>some text 4</div>"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My jQuery code

```
function openList()
{
    var getTitletxt = $(this).find('a').attr("title");
    console.log(getTitletxt);
}
```

I'm getting `undefined` in my console.log. Basically i'm trying to fetch text inside title div.

Comment: first close <a> tag `<a title="<div>some text 1</div>"> </a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use inline event handlers. You can use `on` for binding events.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="myClass">
<!--       ^^^^^^^^^ -->
    <div class="inc">
        <div class="iWrap"> <a title="<div>blah1 blah1</div>">a</a>
            <a title="<div>blah2 blah2</div>">b</a>
            <a title="<div>blah3 blah3</div>">c</a>
            <a title="<div>blah4 blah4</div>">d</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="myClass">
<!--     ^^^^^^^^^ -->
    <div class="inc">
        <div class="iWrap"> <a title="<div>some text 1</div>">aa</a>
            <a title="<div>some text 2</div>">bb</a>
            <a title="<div>some text 3</div>">cc</a>
            <a title="<div>some text 4</div>">dd</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**:

```
$('.myClass').on('click', 'a', function() {
    alert($(this).attr('title'));
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/zfboe9o1/

Answer (score 2):

Pass current object using `this`, by default this is not available of you bind handler use javascript inline handler. Your title is also not valid, you problably need on text that is not enclosed in div.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x69tkgak/1/)

```
<div onClick="openList(this);">

function openList(obj)
{
    var getTitletxt = $(obj).find('a').attr("title");
    console.log(getTitletxt );
}
```

Change

```
<a title="<div>some text 1</div>"</a>
```

To

```
<a title="some text 1"> anchor 1 </a>
```

For custom tooltip class you can make css class, I took it from answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927640/styling-native-tooltip-from-title-tooltip-text).

[Live demo with tool tip custom style](http://jsfiddle.net/x69tkgak/2/)

```
a.ac[title]:hover:after 
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works. . but i need custom css for my title.. so the div tag inside a title.. which works very fine.

Answer (score 1):

First close your  Tag.

```
<a title="<div>some text 1</div>"> </a>
```

Pass `this` as parameter in function

```
  <div onClick="openList(this);">

   function openList($this)   
   {
     $($this).find('a').each(function(){  // To get all <a> tag title
        var getTitletxt = $(this).attr("title");
        console.log(getTitletxt );
     }); 
  }
```