# Customizing default tooltip using css

Tags: css, html

I know there are a lot of examples for customizing the tooltip of an html element but I can't make it working.

I have a simple anchor that looks like the following:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tooltipItem" title="Email address that can be used to contact you." tabindex="-1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right">?</a>
```

And then I created the following css style (I copied from an example):

```
a[title]:hover:after {
  content: attr(title);
  padding: 4px 8px;
  color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1111ee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0, #eeeeee),color-stop(1, #cccccc));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #11eeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
}
```

As you can see in the fiddle I created, the result is not what I expect.

So, what do I have to change?

https://jsfiddle.net/Bonomi/36kp45e2/1/

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927640/styling-native-tooltip-from-title-tooltip-text

Comment: top:1% instead of 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make the positioning of the a tag relative

```
a[title] {
  position: relative;
}
```

That way your tooltip will now be absolute to the anchor tag, not to the document.

Updated fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/36kp45e2/2/