# JavaScript to Change Tooltip to Uppercase

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

Is there a method in JavaScript to change a tooltip/title attribute to all uppercase? I know that tooltips can't be controlled through CSS, but I don't know anything about JavaScript.

I need to only change it on specific elements if possible.

Thank you for any information.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using bootstrap, just apply **"text-uppercase"** to the tooltip element. It will automatically convert it to uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript's `.toUpperCase()` in the following way using jQuery:

```
$('#SomeSelectorOfToolTip').attr('title', $('#SomeSelectorOfToolTip').text().toUpperCase())
```

Comment: Unfortunately none of these solutions have worked. I am not using Bootstrap. The site I am editing is a hosted forum and I do not have direct control over the tooltips; I can only modify them using outside methods.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about the default tooltip which appears upon mousing over an element with a title, you will have to do this by manipulating the title itself. You can access the title property through the DOM with:

```
var newTitle = document.getElementById("myElement")[0].title.toUpperCase
document.getElementById("myElement")[0].title = newTitle
```

Now this is, of course, inherently more difficult than simply changing the title itself, but if these are the criteria for what you are trying to accomplish it should work.

**UPDATE**

It appears there may be a pure CSS solution actually. Take a look at the top answer to this question: [Styling native tooltip from title="Tooltip text"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927640/styling-native-tooltip-from-title-tooltip-text)