# How to customize the browser default title position of a input field using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Failed to customize the browser default title position of a input field using Javascript.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myP").title = "Title Top the input field";
  //document.getElementById("myP").title.position=  'top'; //Wrong
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <input id="myP" title="Title below the input field" />
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In my eyes it is not possible, because this comes from browser. If you want to have a different tooltip, you have to develop it by yourself (or using an framework)

Comment: You failed, because what you want is impossible ... no idea what even made you think this was possible in the first place. If you want a tooltip that allows you to specify such stuff, you need to use a custom solution that create and positions HTML elements to achieve the effect. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927640/styling-native-tooltip-from-title-tooltip-text

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17579580/4108884 - this actually can achieve it. Just manipulate the top, bottom, left, right of a[title]:hover:after as you see fit.

Comment: @SamuilPetrov, The issue I am facing is that the default tooltip is overlying on my custom tooltip which is showing the value of the input field if it had a long text.

Comment: this is what you can do ,clone you button ,set it's new tool tip and add it to div and then remove previous button