# hide title attribute from link on mouse hover with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the title attribute in all my links but I don't want to be visible on mouse hover, but still visible in the code for screen readers.

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    if (links[i].className == 'suppress') {
    links[i]._title = links[i].title;
    links[i].onmouseover = function() { 
    this.title = '';
}

links[i].onmouseout = function() { 
    this.title = this._title;
}
```

Comment: You are using jQuery, why do you use such a long code? It can be very simple!

Comment: exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809795/suppress-link-titles

Comment: Why don't you want tooltips for your users? If there's relevant data, show it to them - both screenreaders and visual browsers; else don't use title attributes at all.

Answer (score 4):

Using jQuery, you can hide the `title` attr on hover, and replace it on mouseout:

```
$(function(){

    $('a').hover(function(e){

        $(this).attr('data-title', $(this).attr('title'));
        $(this).removeAttr('title');

    },
    function(e){

        $(this).attr('title', $(this).attr('data-title'));

    });​

});
```

Like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2nHxV/).

Comment: Which browser are you using? Works fine here in OS X Chrome.

Comment: ie9, chrome Version 22.0.1229.79 m, firefox15.0.1

Comment: Have you tried the fiddle? If you are trying it your page, be sure to include jQuery library and to wrap the code in the `$(function(){ ... });` wrapper - see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using jQuery, you can do it in a simple way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").removeAttr("title");
});
```

Or, setting it to empty value:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").attr("title", "");
});
```

If this is gonna change the way the screen readers read, then, you can just target on hover.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").hover(function(){
        $(this).attr("rel", $(this).attr("title"));
        $(this).removeAttr("title");
    }, function(){
        $(this).attr("title", $(this).attr("rel"));
        $(this).removeAttr("rel");
    });
});
```

Comment: he said "still visible in the code for screen readers". would the screen reader still be able to read it after removed?

Comment: Hmm.. Yeah, will change the code and update the answer in a few seconds. :)

Comment: `rel` is for storing link relationship, not for custom data: use `data-whatever` better.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to create a bubble tool-tip in CSS but the browser tool-tip would always appear and mess things up. So, like you, I needed to disable the default tool-tip.

I used a bit of JQuery to remove the "Title" tag but only on mouse hover. As soon as the mouse is out, the "Title" tag is restored.

Following is a DIV with some "Title" content:

```
<div class="tooltip-class" title="This is some information for our tooltip.">
  This is a test
</div>
```

Now you can run the following JQuery to hide the Title tag on mouse hover:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".tooltip-class").hover(function(){
    $(this).attr("tooltip-data", $(this).attr("title"));
    $(this).removeAttr("title");
  }, function(){
    $(this).attr("title", $(this).attr("tooltip-data"));
    $(this).removeAttr("tooltip-data");
  });
});
```

Following is a link to the full example:

http://jsfiddle.net/eliasb/emG6E/54/

Answer (score 0):

$(".element").hover(function(){

```
    // Get the current title
    var title = $(this).attr("title");

    // Store it in a temporary attribute
    $(this).attr("tmp_title", title);

    // Set the title to nothing so we don't see the tooltips
    $(this).attr("title","");

});
```

$(".element").click(function(){// Fired when we leave the element

```
    // Retrieve the title from the temporary attribute
    var title = $(this).attr("tmp_title");

    // Return the title to what it was
    $(this).attr("title", title);

});
```

Comment: Please format code properly and give some explanation to your answer