# Mouse over shows HTML for Lightbox2 and Milkbox photos

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lightbox2

I'm using Lightbox2 for a slideshow of photos from thumbnails contained in a table.  My page is doing exactly what I want for the slideshow and captions.  However, when in the initial page before clicking on a thumbnail to start the slideshow, if I mouseover a thumbnail photo in the table a small box opens (like a tooltip box) showing the HTML code for the table, Lightbox options, photos, etc.  How I can suppress this display?

By the way this does not happen in Milkbox with similar code.

And finally, this behavior does not happen if I remove the Lightbox code so that clicking on a thumbnail opens up the full sized image of that thumbnail.

Here is some sample code which I have modified as the page exists on our intranet:

```
<table><tr>
<td id="mb1" align="center"><a id="mb1a" href="Photo1.jpg" data-lightbox="ga1" 
title="<table style='width:100%'><tr><td  style='width: 50%; border: 1px solid  #FFFFFF'<center>IGN Map</center></td><td style='width: 20'></td><td style='width:     50%; border: 1px solid #FFFFFF'><center>Carte IGN</center></span></td></tr>
<tr><td style='width: 50%; border: 1px solid #FFFFFF'>Right Click and choose 'Save Picture as...' to download this photo</td><td style='width: 20'></td>
<td style='width: 50%; border: 1px solid #FFFFFF'>Cliquer droit et choisir 'enregistrer l'image sous...' pour telecharger cette photo</td></tr></table>">
<img border="0" src="/thumbnail/Photo1.jpg" height="135" width="227" align="middle"/></a><br/>Map</td>

<td id="mb1" align="center"><a id="mb1a" href="Photo2.jpg" data-lightbox="ga1" 
title="<table style='width:100%'><tr><td  style='width: 50%; border: 1px solid #FFFFFF'><center>Google Earth</center></td><td style='width: 20'></td>
<td style='width: 50%; border: 1px solid #FFFFFF'><center>Google Earth</center></td></tr>
<tr><td style='width: 50%; border: 1px solid #FFFFFF'>Right Click and choose 'Save Picture as...' to download this photo</td><td style='width: 20'></td>
<td style='width: 50%; border: 1px solid #FFFFFF'>Cliquer droit et choisir 'enregistrer l'image sous...' pour telecharger cette photo</td></tr></table>">
<img border="0" src="/thumbnail/Photo2.jpg" height="96" width="227" align="middle"/></a><br/>Map2</td>

<td id="mb1" align="center"><a id="mb1a" href="Photo3.jpg" data-lightbox="ga1" 
title="<table style='width:100%'><tr><td  style='width: 50%; border: 1px solid #FFFFFF'><center>Profile</center></td><td style='width: 20'></td>
<td style='width: 50%; border: 1px solid #FFFFFF'><center>Profil</center></td></tr>
<tr><td style='width: 50%; border: 1px solid #FFFFFF'>Right Click and choose 'Save Picture as...' to download this photo</td><td style='width: 20'></td>
<td style='width: 50%; border: 1px solid #FFFFFF'>Cliquer droit et choisir 'enregistrer l'image sous...' pour telecharger cette photo</td></tr></table>">
<img border="0" src="/thumbnail/Photo3.jpg" height="164" width="227" align="middle"/></a><br/>Profile</td>
</tr></table>
```

The javascript and CCS files are as downloaded from the web

Comment: well if you post your code we can help. please edit your question and add the code

Comment: Show us the code before it is loaded. So in your plain text editor.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.  My issues was very similar to the issue in this link [hide title attribute from link on mouse hover with javascript/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12663433/hide-title-attribute-from-link-on-mouse-hover-with-javascript-jquery)

A slight modification of that answer fixed my problem

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){

$('a').hover(function(e){

    $(this).attr('data-title', $(this).attr('title'));
    $(this).removeAttr('title');

},

function(e){

    $(this).attr('title', $(this).attr('data-title'));

});
$('a').click(function(e){
    $(this).attr('title',$(this).attr('data-title'));});
```

});